# Learning SQL in a week (SQL Server and PL SQL (Oracle))

Tags: sql, sql-server, plsql

Just picking your brain on this.

Is it possible to learn complex SQL syntax in a week (PL SQL)?

I have some basic knowledge of it however, not a great deal.

I have used SQL Server previously and learnt the basic Insert, Update, Delete, Inner Join, Left Outter etc. But, since I have not used it in a long time it is a bit rusty. How long do you think it will take to get a firm grip on it?

Thanks all

Comment: Do realize that we don't know you. How fast someone can pick up something depends a whole lot on that person. (But you won't get more than basics in a week, for just about any non-trivial subject, CS or otherwise.)

Comment: Ok. thanks for that Mat, I will try to prove you wrong :). I picked up VBA in about 2 weeks. I have  6 years of experience in Java development prior, which probably made it easier. Just not to sure about SQL as I haven't had a great deal of exposure since university days.

Comment: VBA's _designed_ to be usable by just about anyone.

Comment: First thing to learn: PL/SQL is only for stored procedures. It is not a query language, it's a procedural language. Oracle makes a very clear distinction between the two.

Comment: @Mat and you're telling me TSQL and PLSQL aren't designed to be usable by just about anyone? lol

Comment: @user3608262: no, I'm telling you PL/SQL isn't not designed specifically to be picked up quickly by non-programmers. Sure you'll get a grip of it fast enough, mastering it will take a whole lot more time though, especially since that requires a lot of knowledge about the database itself. (I don't know TSQL.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PL/SQL is inspired by Ada/Pascal. If you know the latter, you "know" the syntax of PL/SQL.
But "really know" SQL is not just about the syntax. It's about how the stuff works. If you know what's O(log n) and what's O(n log n) - you'll get it fast. If not, well, you'll be having much troubles all the time.

Comment: PL/SQL and SQL are two completely different things.

Comment: Well, "different" - yes, but not "completely different", as PL/SQL is thought to be "the procedural extension" of SQL (which is a declarative one). Though, there's a huge distance between "procedural" and "declarative". But I guess, the TS mentioned PL/SQL as "some kind of advanced SQL topics". So my answer is.

Comment: SQL is a query language. PL/SQL is not. PL/SQL will let you run SQL statements as part of the PL/SQL program, similar to other programming languages (Java, C#) that will let you run SQL statements.  The integration of SQL into the program code is much tighter though - but this is not unique to PL/SQL. PowerBuilder has a similar way of integrating SQL statement inside it's programming language - but that does not make PowerScript the same as "SQL". When learning Oracle, this distinction is **vital** to understanding the product.

Comment: You're right. But TS asked of both at once. Moreover, he asked about SQL, PL/SQL and sql-server, while the latter, AFAIK, has only T-SQL.

Comment: I think user3608262 actually doesn't know the difference. Many people assume that PL/SQL is just the name for Oracle's SQL dialect, similar to the way that "T-SQL" is Microsoft's name for their SQL dialect - but they don't understand that there are *two* languages in Oracle (whereas SQL Server does not make any distinction between procedural code and "normal" SQL)